# Read Memory Values (Real time) Best practice

Tags: c++, memory

I have successfully read data from a game via C++. Now I need to read it in so that the GUI updates with correct value all the time. I have two concerns:

1. Do I use an infinite while loop?

   ```
   while(gameOn) {
       ReadAddress(1); //Example
       ReadAddress(2); //Example
       ReadAddress(3); //Example
       ReadAddress(4); //Example
       ....
       ReadAddress(100); //Example
       Sleep(200);
   }
   ```
2. As you can see one while loop will end up reading a lot of game values. Since the value is consecutive (I am suspecting it is a structure), should I just read 100 bytes and parse it? So the option is reading 100 bytes once and process the data accordingly or reading 1 byte each time for 100 times.

By the way here is my read function

```
int Process::memoryReadByte(int memoryAddress) {
    unsigned char buffer = 0;
    SIZE_T NumberOfBytesToRead = sizeof(buffer); //this is equal to 1
    SIZE_T NumberOfBytesActuallyRead;
    BOOL succeed = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)(baseAddress + memoryAddress), &buffer, NumberOfBytesToRead, &NumberOfBytesActuallyRead);
    if (!succeed || NumberOfBytesActuallyRead != NumberOfBytesToRead) {
        return 0;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

So is infinite while loop good? I don't want to make my game laggy. Infinite while loop sounds scary.

Comment: Infinite loops are fine. What you may want to do is add in wait statements so you are not using too much cpu.

Comment: One alternative to polling the memory for changes would be to hook `WriteProcessMemory` (or `NtWriteVirtualMemory`).

Comment: If the memory is contiguous, I would definitely read everything at once, especially if it's just 100 bytes. If the values have some relationship, you would have to worry about consistency if you read them at different times, so the closer together they are read, the better. Also performance will be better with just one function call instead of 100.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do need to use a loop to read memory to keep your local copies updated.

If the memory is contiguous you should read all the contiguous memory in one call to ReadProcessMemory() and then parse the local buffer.  This will make your program more efficient because ReadProcessMemory has the overhead of multiple internal API calls and security checks etc...